# Passing environment variables to remote server as a different user

Tags: linux, ssh, environment-variables

I'm trying to set environmental variables while I SSH into a remote server on a CentOS server. I am running the command as root but need it to run a command as the Oracle user. I found a few things on the site but none of the appear to work.

```
ssh $SERVER su $ORACLE_USER 'ORACLE_HOME="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0"; PATH="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/Opatch:$PATH';  opatch lsiinventory'
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most shells, variables aren't automatically part of the environment until they're *exported* there (in Bourne shell terminology). For sh/bash, use:

```
ssh $SERVER "su $ORACLE_USER -c 'export ORACLE_HOME=\"/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0\";
                                 export PATH=\"/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/Opatch:\$PATH\";
                                 opatch lsiinventory'"
```

(In bash, changing an existing environment variable such as $PATH will automatically re-export it, but that's not guaranteed to be true in all shells.)

Also note that `ssh` *does not* preserve argument separation and sends everything as a single parameter (which is eventually given to `/bin/sh -c "…"`). To avoid confusion, it might be best to only pass a single command parameter to ssh in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a small shell script launcher on the far system and run it:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0
exec $ORACLE_HOME/Opatch/opatch lsiinventory
```

Save that into a file called something like "oplauncher" chmod 755 it, and use ssh to logon and run it.